# Symmetries- Table of group of symmetries

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do you go about listing the symmetries of say letters V or Z or along that line and their tables? Its too vague for me to understand what they are asking for i know the given theorem requires 4 things closure associativity identity and inverses and i know how to prove if a group is a symmetric group on its associated set but i don't know how to approach a question like this..no detailed answers required just an idea how to approach this thank you in advance

Comment: A more precise statement of the question would be helpful.

Comment: The question states "list the symmetries of the letters Z and give the table of this group of symmetries and do the same for letters V and X."

Comment: From what i've learned on symmetry and groups thus far i don't know how to approach this question and with what information

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought that might be what you were asking but I wasn't sure. The symmetries of a geometric figure would be all the operations you can perform on the shape (reflections, rotation, etc.) that leave the shape unchanged. For instance "X" has two axes about which it can be reflected without changing the shape. The tranformations which leave the shape unchanged can be thought of as the elements of a group.

Try reading the first chapter of this book "Algebra and Concrete"(free and online) and see if it helps:http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/algebrabook.html

Comment: So basically we have to treat the Z as an object? but why does the question say "letters Z"? that throws me off a bit

Comment: I didn't write the problem so I can't be sure but I suspect the said "letter Z" to emphasize that Z was standing for a shape rather than the element of some group. Its also possible that I completely misunderstood the question but this is something that is done in the context of group theory. For instance you could consider the rotation group as being a subgroup of all the transformations which leave a sphere unchanged.